# OpenWhisk/Node -- Promise Is Not Resolving

Tags: node.js, promise, ibm-cloud, serverless, openwhisk

I've tested a reddit bot locally for a while now, and gotten it working locally. So now I'm trying to invoke it on OpenWhisk. The line where my troubles seem to come up is:

```
r.getInbox( {"filter":"mentions", "append":false } ).then( newMentions, console.err );
```

newMentions is never triggered. I've made the first line in it a console.log, and I've replaced newMentions with console.log.

console.logs before and after this line get called just fine, and getInbox works fine on my local machine and should work just fine here. I'm not getting any error anywhere, even from console.err in the above line.

So my current guess is that my OpenWhisk instance somehow ends before getInbox can resolve. Is that right? I have it set to 60s/512mb, and it's not taking anywhere near 60s, and I can't imagine it takes up 512mb. So... Do I need to manually force OpenWhisk to wait for the promise to resolve? How would I do that? Or is there some other error I'm not seeing?

To be clear: I'm using snoowrap for reddit. r is a proper snoowrap object, and getInbox is a snoowrap function that I'm pretty sure I'm using correctly, which returns a promise for json data representing an inbox. And again, even if it were empty, newMentions should still be called, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

return the promise to the main function

```
function main(){
  return r.getInbox( {"filter":"mentions", "append":false } ).then( newMentions, console.error );
}
```

this way OpenWhisk will wait on the Promise

make sure your resolve function `newMentions` or reject function returns a JSON object, it will be the result of the Action

Also `console.err` is not a function is `console.error`

Comment: Well now where did I get console.err from?

Anyway, it's now... kind of working, so thanks!